# Ranking criteria for the same frequency words in Tokenizer() and working of Tokenizer().texts_to_matrix() in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

For the text list,

```
sent = ["I am whatever you say I am and if I wasn't, why would you say I am" , 
        'but but but, anyways, it is still me because I am me']

tokenizer_obj = Tokenizer(num_words=15)

tokenizer_obj.fit_on_texts(sent)
```

You get the  answer from `tokenizer_obj.texts_to_sequences(sent)`

as

```
>>> [[1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 8, 9, 1, 10, 11, 12, 4, 5, 1, 2],
     [3, 3, 3, 13, 14, 6, 1, 2, 6]]
```

and from `tokenizer_obj.word_index`, a dict of words based on frequency as

```
{'i': 1,
 'am': 2,
 'but': 3,
 'you': 4,
 'say': 5,
 'me': 6,
 'whatever': 7,
 'and': 8,
 'if': 9,
 "wasn't": 10,
 'why': 11,
 'would': 12,
 'anyways': 13,
 'it': 14,
 'is': 15,
 'still': 16,
 'because': 17}
```

I get that the raking is based on the most frequent words but what if there is a tie and there is in my case for the words in the dict where is frequency is 1 for all the words. What is the criteria for that because I don't see any pattern in that.

Plus  the code, `tokenizer_obj.texts_to_matrix(sent)` returns a matrix in binary as

```
>>> array([[0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
           [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

What does that stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a simpler example.

```
sent = ["I am whatever you say say"]
```

If there's a tie in the frequency the next in line would be the "order" the words appeared. The words appeared first gets the lower id. You can verify this with the following example.

```
tokenizer_obj = Tokenizer(num_words=6)
tokenizer_obj.fit_on_texts(sent)
print(tokenizer_obj.word_index)
```

Which gives,

```
>>> {'say': 1, 'i': 2, 'am': 3, 'whatever': 4, 'you': 5}
```

Here you can see that the word "say" (most frequent) gets the lowest ID and the rest is followed by the order they appear in the corpus.

### What does `texts_to_matrix` do?

It's simply a binary vector (`num_words`) elements long. Value at each index indicates whether that word (with the ID indicated by the index) is present in the data or not. E.g. If we take the word "I" (which has ID 2), the element at index 2 is set to 1.

```
print(tokenizer_obj.texts_to_matrix(sent))
```

```
>>> [[0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

You might note the leading 0. 0 is a reversed ID in the keras Tokenizer, used to indicate padding. So that will become 1 only if you have padding in your sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the help and now it looks obvious too. Can you help me with the significance of  num_words=15 parameter in Tokenizer()? How and where is it useful?

Comment: @Deshwal, num_words is to control the vocabulary size. It helps to get rid of rare words (which doesn't add much value to the learning) conveniently. Because when you set num_words low, it's the rarest words that gets ignored.

Comment: but it doesn't matter if I use 8 or 5000, my  ```len(tokenizer.word_index) +1```   is always the same.

Comment: @Deshwal, tokenizer always create mappings for all words. You'd see the difference only when you use methods like `texts_to_sequences` and `texts_to_matrix`.